# Is there currently a way to test Microsoft Edge on OSX?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, microsoft-edge

I don't see a VM for Edge listed on http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/

Is there currently a way to do this?

Comment: It is when you're testing web code browser compatibility :):):)

Comment: @JAL why do you think that testing for example a web application under different browsers or operating systems for compatibility would not be a question related to "programming"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browserstack has Edge available as one of its options. In addition, you can try out the [remote.modern.ie](https://remote.modern.ie/) to test this via a free cloud version of Windows 10

Comment: The Edge in BrowserStack is not the most recent version (as confirmed by a BrowserStack support member, they are using "Windows Server Technical Preview 2 (build 10074)"). Also remote.modern.ie gives me access to IE11, not Edge.

Comment: That URL is 404. A new URL to test Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/

Answer (score 3):

[Link to all of this, and more resources on GitHub](https://github.com/deltakosh/interoperable-web-development/tree/master/testing)

**Testing the application using RemoteIE & BrowserStack**

There are several ways of testing websites, aside from the good old-fashioned way of using a device lab and physically looking at your site on multiple devices and in multiple browsers. Two of the more popular and easier ways to go about testing include modern.IE remoteIE and BrowserStack.

**RemoteIE**

RemoteIE is a free service offered by modern.IE that allows you to connect to a hosted version of the latest IE builds running in the cloud using a client. This client, called the Azure RemoteApp Client, is available for Mac OS X, iOS, Android and Windows OS devices, and includes simple installation and account set up steps. The available IE builds run on Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise. In this preview version of the service, only public URLs and IP addresses can be accessed.

**Other tools offered by modern.IE include:**

Virtual Machines with versions of IE ranging from IE6 to IE11, that can be downloaded and managed in your own development environment.
Browser Screenshots of how your site looks across nine common browsers and devices.

Compatibility reports generated from analyzing your site while it runs to detect patterns of interactions known to cause issues in browsers.
Site scans for common coding problems in your website.

**BrowserStack**

RemoteIE has partnered with BrowserStack to provide interactive browser testing in the cloud, regardless of the platform, and within your own browser.

BrowserStack is a paid online service, but you can sign up for a free trial. With BrowserStack it is possible to test internal websites or local html designs using remote browsers after configuring for local testing, so the website does not have to be live to test it out. Signing up for the free trial gives you a 30-minute session to test the website in a broad range of platforms and browsers. The full list of browsers & mobile devices for live testing can be found here.